# Where can I find the Angular 2 CDN or source code?

Tags: angular

I've been trying to download the source code from angular 2, but I was unable to find it. I looked in their github repository, but couldn't identify the correct one. Can someone point me the one or a working CDN so I can download it?

Edit: I need to get the source without using Node.Js and NPM.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use unpkg.com:

https://unpkg.com/@angular/core@4.0.1/bundles/core.umd.js

https://unpkg.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.0.1/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js

and so on.

Here is **[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yurzui/1hk7knwq/)**

```typescript
let { Component, NgModule } = ng.core;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello, {{ name }}</h1>
    <button (click)="increment()">Click {{ counter }}</button>
  `,
})
class HomeComponent {
    counter = 0;
    name = 'Angular 2'

    increment() {
        this.counter++;
    }
}

const { BrowserModule } = ng.platformBrowser;

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ HomeComponent ]
})
class AppModule { }
```

If you don't want to use typescript then here is

[**Plunker Example Angular es5**](https://plnkr.co/edit/qEsRoPeUs3iMdqKQhGVR?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

Normally you would use angular.io to download the quick-start or CLI using NPM etc. Here is a copy of the CDN:

https://gist.github.com/johnpapa/dd9b8a06bf93f4b38a3e