# Is it possible to use angular with a cdn?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to use angular with a CDN instead of installing it from npm?
My NPM install was getting stuck so I was wondering is it possible to use angular with a CDN.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the Angular 2 CDN or source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127422/where-can-i-find-the-angular-2-cdn-or-source-code)

Comment: No, this does not